# Storing folder's paths

Tags: c

Where can I store folder's paths, which can be accessed from every function/variable in a C program?
Ex. I have an executable called do_input.exe in the path `c:\tests\myprog\bin\do_input.exe`,
another one in `C:\tools\degreesToDms.exe`, etc. how and where should I store these?

I stored them as strings in an header file which I included in every project's file but someone discouraged from doing this. Are they right?

Comment: what was that someone's rationale for discouraging you from doing this?  will these paths change dynamically or will they always stay the same?

Comment: If those paths stay the same, it's fine to define them in a header file. But if they change frequently, you're better off by using a fixed configuration file which contains the paths to the needed files.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann: they always stay the same. But do you think it would make difference if they vary?

Comment: It certainly won't work for someone who doesn't have a `C:` drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I stored them as strings in an header file which I included in every project's file but someone discouraged from doing this. Are they right?

Yes, they are absolutely right: "baking in" installation-specific strings with paths in a file system into a compiled code is not a good decision, because you must recompile simply to change locations of some key files. This limits the flexibility of other members of your team to run your tests, and may prevent your tests from being ran automatically in an automated testing environment.

A better solution would use a plain text configuration file with the locations of the key directories, and functions that read that file and produce correct locations at run-time.

Alternatively, you could provide locations of key directories as command-line parameters to your program. This way, users who run your program would be able to set correct locations without recompiling.

Comment: If I have all the paths into my project's path?

Comment: @A_nto2 The larger your team, the less desirable it becomes to rely on fixed locations. You can design a scheme of referencing directories relative to the location of your exe file for convenience, then your program would be able to find all the files relative to your project's path. But an explicit override might still be desirable for situations when your program runs in automated testing environments.

Comment: I was meaning, if I have all the executables and files into one big folder. They all stays into this folder. So in this case can I use the .h?

Comment: @A_nto2 If you go the `.h` route, at the bare minimum you should let the users override your default choice in one way or the other. The only case that I know a `.h` with no overrides is going to work for sure is when you are the only developer *and* you are also the only user of your program; once a second user enters into the picture, he'll start complaining about your choice of the directory as soon as he or she runs into the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

If they stay the same, then I don't see any problem defining these paths in a "`.h`" header file included in all the various .c files that reference the paths.  But every computer this thing will be running on may have different paths ("`Tests`" instead of "`test`"), so this is super risky programming and probably only safe if you're running it on a single machine or a set of machines that you control directly.

If the paths will *change*, then you need to create a storage place for these paths (e.g. static character array, etc.) and then have methods to allow these to be fetched and possibly reset dynamically (e.g. instead of writing output files to "`results`", maybe the user wants to change things to write files to "`/tmp`").  Totally depends on what you are doing in your code and what the tools you're writing will be doing.

Comment: You can modify them in a "`.h`" file, but then they are compiled and baked into the executables.  If any paths / directories are different on other machines you install the tools on, you're likely to run into problems.